# How to restore 'sort by position' option for category sorting

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-sorting

In our store the sort by position (ie 'Best Value') option is not being shown when viewing categories. I believe this was removed/hidden by someone in the past but now we want to show it again.

I have checked all the common areas for this and can't find where/how it has been removed. For instance, all categories have all the sort options selected under the "Available Product Listing Sort By" list - the 'Best Value' option is not deselected for any category:

[image]

Also, i've checked and `app/design/frontend/our/theme/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` does not exclude the 'position' attribute. I tried echoing the output of `$this->getAvailableOrders()` in `toolbar.phtml` and the list does not include the position field so I assume that position is somehow being removed via code before the template is rendered.

How can I find where/how position is being removed from the product sort options?

We are running Magento 1.9.3.8 CE.

Answer (score 1):

We found the culprit - the Amasty Improved Sorting extension was removing the sort by position attribute as per the following setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not have the Amasty better sorting extension and wish to know how to set the position as the default category sorting option:

'Best value' is the same as 'Position'. I do not know why they gave the same value different names.

The value is 0 to 9, with 0 being the best value through to 9 being the least.

I had the same issue can confirm this works. Hope it helps. Cheers.